# Where do "Suggest a technology for X" questions go?

Tags: support, subjective, example-questions

OP tells about his project and asks which technologies/frameworks might be suitable for him.

Where do these kinds of questions go?

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: These questions are extremely interesting but unfortunately many times closed as subjective and argumentative... (as a controversy, these are usualy the most interesting ones...).

Comment: What tools should I use to to build a house?

Comment: @Shog9 We call that a troll.

Comment: You only call it a troll because it's more obviously off-topic. Imagine if it were posted on [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I'm just jaded, but I've seen exactly zero *well-asked* "what tech should I use" questions.

I'd argue that they belong nowhere, as they are subjective to the extreme and are hard to *ask* in a way that would satisfy the requirements of [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

A major problem is that a valid answer would have to know what the OP is actually capable of and comfortable with, and this information is generally missing from most of these questions.  Further, if it comes down to a comparison between two technologies that the OP is trying to decide between, it's often very difficult to both answer the question and stay within the subjectivity guidelines.

Comment: I can imagine some well-asked "what tech should I use" questions, including enough specific details to actually provide good answers. But I don't think this solves the whole problem with them. Even if they're well-asked, it's too likely that they're not well-answered. And they're still not a good fit for a Q&A site, as they'll often lead to extended discussion and argument.

Answer (score -2):

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) (emphasis added):

> FWIW, **questions about tools are totally on-topic for Stack Overflow.**
>   Questions about *choosing* tools are on-topic, with some caveats. **It's
>   open-ended "give me a grocery list" questions that tend to raise ire.**

[Anna Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155160/anna-lear) (again, emphasis added):

> **Questions about programming tools are usually things like "how do I do
>   X in [editor of choice]?"** They're still fundamentally practical and
>   answerable. As Shog9 said, **the "let's build a list of tools" questions
>   tend to not do well.**
>
> Architecture questions are fine... when they're specific and have
>   some defined requirements/constraints. **Most questions about choosing
>   the right technology we get are incredibly generic down to "give me
>   your favourite tools! anything goes!".**

Comment: Paging Anna Lear to post 102191... (no, it's off-topic on programmers too)

Comment: On the grounds of being too subjective, I assume? To be honest, that's what I was afraid of—and the reason for the question mark in my answer—but I still find it strange that Stack Exchange doesn't have a place for questions like this; they could be useful, if phrased properly. Not to mention that the [Programmer's FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) states, "If your question is about programming tools, please ask on Stack Overflow instead." Instead, it should probably say, "If your question is about programming tools, please don't ask on Stack Exchange sites."

Comment: It gets confusing because in Programmer's FAQ : `What kind of questions can I ask here? ...This can include topics such as ...Architecture`

Comment: I agree. It's understandable that people get confused about this.

Comment: @Chris: FWIW, questions about tools are totally on-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about *choosing* tools are on-topic, with some caveats. It's open-ended "give me a grocery list" questions that tend to raise ire.

Comment: @Chris Questions about programming tools are usually things like "how do I do X in [editor of choice]?" They're still fundamentally practical and answerable. As Shog9 said, the "let's build a list of tools" questions that tend to not do well.

Comment: @rlb.usa Architecture questions are fine... when they're specific and have some defined requirements/constraints. Most questions about choosing the right technology we get are incredibly generic down to "give me your favourite tools! anything goes!".

Comment: As an alternative to marking a post community wiki after you notice it's received 3 or so downvotes, you could just delete it...

Comment: @Cody I actually wanted to leave this post here for the conversation that it generated in the comments and as a counterpoint to the accepted answer. I think that this is advantageous because it clearly demonstrates that Programmers is *not* the right place for a question soliciting recommended tools and provides some more reasons *why*. I understand the reasoning in the accepted answer, but I can't help but feel that it's a bit paternalistic to simply say "[questions asking for tool suggestions] belong nowhere."